# Need To Identify A Specific Element's ID In An Individual Record Of An ASP.net Datalist

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Using VB.net. 
I have a webpage with an asp.net datalist with a table in the datalist.  Using the click of an image (located in the individual datalist record) I want to hide one of the rows of the table within the same datalist record.  I’m using an image with a javascript onclick and the datalists' ItemDataBound to accomplish this.  Can't get it to work. Nothing happens.

```
Protected Sub DataList1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles DataList1.ItemDataBound
Dim imgDetails As HtmlImage = CType(e.Item.FindControl("imgDetails"), HtmlImage)
Dim detailsTR As HtmlTableRow = CType(e.Item.FindControl("detailsTR"), HtmlTableRow)
imgDetails.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:document.getElementById('" & detailsTR.ID & "').style.display = 'none';")

End Sub
```

The problem I believe is either with the ID within a datalist or maybe my javascript is off (although I can get it all to work outside a datalist).  Maybe there is a way (ClientID??) to set a unique ID for table row in each record of the datalist????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Access the ClientID of a control like this...

```
CType(e.Item.FindControl("imgDetails"), HtmlImage).ClientID
```

OR Also, in your datalist you can use :<%#Container.ItemIndex %> to give your rows a unique index, then you can Access it in your code behind.

```
<asp:datalist id="DataList1" runat="server">
    <itemtemplate>
        <%#Container.ItemIndex+1 %>
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:datalist>
```

Comment: That works - thanks highwingers.  I accessed the clientID and used that in the javascript.  Much appreciated.